# How to programmatically create a connection with [Plugin: Posts 2 Posts] on cpt publish?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, publish, plugin-posts-to-posts

**How can I programmatically create a connection between one custom post type, cpt, (with post id known) to another on cpt on publish?**

I am using [VoodooPress's front-end posting method](http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/add-a-meta-box-to-use-custom-fields-on-front-end-post-form/) to publish a post type called *post-type-A*. One input field in the *post-type-A* form is the public inventory number, which through some wp_query love gives me the post id of the *post-type-B* that I wish to create a relationship with.

I know that I can use [this](http://wpcanyon.com/tipsandtricks/adding-a-custom-field-automatically-on-postpage-publish/) function to create a one-way connection from *post-type-A* to *post-type-B* using a custom field.

```
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'field-name', 'custom value', true);
    }
}
```

But how do I programmatically create a connection using @Scribu's [Posts 2 Posts](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts) plugin? A two-way relationship would reduce a lot of hassle and programming time.  :)

For reference, the snippet below is the [connect api reference](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/posts-to-posts/tags/0.2/api.php#L41) for the plugin...

```
/**
 * Connect a post to another one
 *
 * @param int $post_a The first end of the connection
 * @param int $post_b The second end of the connection
 * @param bool $bydirectional Wether the connection should be bydirectional
 */
function p2p_connect( $post_a, $post_b, $bydirectional = false ) {
        add_post_meta( $post_a, P2P_META_KEY, $post_b );

        if ( $bydirectional )
                add_post_meta( $post_b, P2P_META_KEY, $post_a );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `p2p_connect( $id_of_post_type_a, $id_of_post_type_b );` in the form handling code.

Comment: Update: as seen on here: [link](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts/p2p-0-9-5.html) this has changed to: `p2p_type( 'YOUR_CONNECTION_TYPE' )->connect`. More on the p2posts wiki: [link](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Creating-connections-programatically)

Comment: @ÁlexAcuñaViera You should post that as an answer, as my answer is clearly outdated. :)