# Creating connections programmatically with common fields on CPT's

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, import, csv, plugin-posts-to-posts

I'm trying to create a programmatic connection between two CPT's that have a common field (id_number). For example:

CPT "City":

post_name:New York

id_number:34

CPT "Color":

post_name:Red

id_number:34

I tryed the examples in the Posts 2 Posts wiki and it was functioning if i choose one by one the posts connections (I have around 4500 posts). I wish it could be done automatically as I have fields in common in both CPT's that could be used (in the above example it was the id_number 34 in both the CPT's).

Based on the same [wiki](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Creating-connections-programmatically), here is how I was thinking it should be done:

```
function my_connection_types() {
p2p_create_connection( 'test_connection', array(
    'from' => 'city',
    'to' => 'color',
    'meta' => array(
        'id_number' => 'id_number'
    )
) );
```

}
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'my_connection_types' );

I also found these [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20566/how-to-programmatically-create-a-connection-with-plugin-posts-2-posts-on-cpt) but i don't understand if it could be used to solve my problem.

Can this be done with Posts 2 Posts? Any help or guidance to the right path would be great. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No need to code for this one as it was already solved by mikemanger with the plugin [Batch Posts 2 Posts](https://bitbucket.org/lighthouseuk/wp-batch-posts-to-posts) for, as the name says, batch creation of relations using Posts 2 Posts plugin framework.

As in their description:

> This plugin makes it easy to create relations using the [Posts 2 Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/)
>   plugin.
>
> For example you create a new "getting-started.pdf" post is your Downloads custom post type.
>   This plugin will let you assign this new post all posts in the "Getting started" post category.
>
> The use cases are limited but it saves you (and your clients) from having to manually go into
>   and edit potentially hundreds of posts.

Thank you!